# Button with selenium python library doesn't do anything when automatically clicked in the site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Here is the function that should be running after a button click in the GUI :

```py
def button_event(self):
        drug1 = self.entry1.get()
        drug2 = self.entry2.get()


        chrome_driver_path = "Chrome driver path "

        # Set Chrome options to run in headless mode
        chrome_options = Options()

        # Create a new Chrome browser instance with the headless option
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)

        # Load the web page
        browser.get('https://go.drugbank.com/drug-interaction-checker')

        # Find the form element by ID
        form = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'form.name-search-form')

        # Find the input fields and fill them out
        name_input = form.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input.select2-search__field')
        name_input.send_keys(drug1)
        time.sleep(2)
        name_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        name_input.send_keys(drug2)
        time.sleep(2)
        name_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        button = form.find_element(By.ID,"search")
        time.sleep(4)
        if button.is_enabled():
            button.click()
            print("button is enabled")
        else :
            description = "Unfound medics in database"
            self.text1.delete("1.0","end")
            self.text1.insert("0.0", description)
            return
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
        new_page_loaded = wait.until(EC.url_contains('drug-interaction-checker#results'))
        time.sleep(2)

        try:
            # Find the element 
            browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2.no-results")
            description = "No interaction found"
            self.text1.delete("1.0","end")
            self.text1.insert("0.0", description)
            return
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("results are there")

        # Find the interactions div and extract the description text
        interactions_div = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.interactions-col.description')
        description = interactions_div.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'p').text
        self.text1.delete("1.0","end")
        self.text1.insert("0.0", description)
```

this should open the `drugBank` web site and enter two meds and then click that button check the interaction, somehow this isn't working because this button even if its clicked nothing happen even manually, but when I go into the site myself everything goes right.

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck?

Comment: if button.is_enabled():
            button.click()
            print("button is enabled")
        else :
            description = "Unfound medics in database"
            self.text1.delete("1.0","end")
            self.text1.insert("0.0", description)
            return

Comment: when the button get clicked the other page isn't loading , nothing happens , the problem is two weeks ago everything works perfectly , but somehow maybe with chrome new version the button click isn't doing anything other than clicking the button without loading the next page

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my Karma is too low to comment, but I feel like this could be useful. Currently when I click on the button manually with a Firefox web browser, nothing happens. Your issue could potentially be due to a different browser/chrome version when testing manually vs automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tested old versions of chrome and webdrivers but still a problem , two weeks ago everything worked perfectly , but now the button click doesn't load the next page

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the button click with :

```
browser.execute_script(
    "document.getElementById('drug-interactions').submit();"
)
```

so this way the button isn t needed and everything works as expected .